# Mathematical tools for iterative / composed function analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, stochastic-analysis, function-and-relation-composition, integral-transforms, stochastic-differential-equations

Given the following: 
a. x0 = known scalar 
b. x1 = known scalar  
c. x2 = unknown scalar 
d. an unknown iteratively applied stochastic nonlinear function $\mathbf{g}$ where 
         $g[x0] = x1+ zg$ 
         $g[x1] = x2 + zg$  where $\mathbf{zg}$ is possibly non-gaussian noise
and  
 
e. a known nonlinear function $\mathbf{f}$  where 
         $f[x0] = x2 + zf$ 
         in a mse sense where $\mathbf{zf}$ is possibly gaussian noise

which given a,b,c,d above implies (with variations d/t introduction of noise)

1. $f[x0] \approx g \circ g [x0] \approx g[x1] $
2. $f[x1] \approx g \circ g \circ g[x0] \approx g \circ g[x1] $
3. $f \circ f[x0] \approx g \circ g \circ f[x0] \approx g \circ g \circ g[x1] $
4. $f \circ f[x1] \approx g \circ g \circ f[x1] \approx g \circ g \circ g \circ g[x1] $

What mathematical tools [Fourier/other transforms, ODE/SDE Theorems, Geometric Algebra, etc]  
can I use to leverage the compositional relationships above and gain insight into

i. the value $x2 \approx g[x1] $  
ii. the relationship between $\mathbf{g}$ and $\mathbf{f}$  
iii. transforms I can do on $\mathbf{f}$ to get closer to the true $\mathbf{g}$? 

The motivation being that f[x0] is a suboptimal estimate, and there may be a transform T that takes advantage of the relationships and reduces noise such that

$\mathbb{E}(  |g[x1]- \mathbf{T}[x0,x1,f[x0],f[x1],f[f[x0]]]|) <  \mathbb{E}( |g[x1] - f[x0]|)$ 
or even 
$\mathbb{E}(  |g[x1]- \mathbf{f} \circ \mathbf{T}[x0,x1,f[x0],f[x1],f[f[x0]]]|) <  \mathbb{E}( |g[x1] - f[x0]|)$